# Novel scifi/detective series, near future, near space

Tags: story-identification

Looking for near future story that takes place within our Solar System.  Do not remember exactly what it was about, but a female, possibly a detective is searching for another, younger female.  One memorable thing is the female searching has luggage, which follows her around.  It is almost a character.  It also protects both itself, and her.

Comment: I won't post it as an answer, since none of the other details fit, but the sapient Luggage as character/protector is one of the most distinctive characteristics of Terry Prachett's *The Color of Magic,* the book that launched his prolific "Discworld" series.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be *[Deepdrive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0380976366)* by Alexander Jablokov? According to reviews like [this one](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/alexander-jablokov/deepdrive/) it takes place within a future version of our solar system that has been settled by multiple alien species, it features a female protagonist named Soph who is looking for a character named Ripi (who is male, not female) who knows the secret of the "deepdrive" that allows for interstellar travel, and the review mentions Soph's "intelligent, self-mobile, armed-to-the-zipper-teeth luggage."

If this isn't it, some extra details might help--do you remember when the book was from, or at least when you read it? What country did you get it in? Do you remember anything about what the cover looked like? Aside from sentient luggage, any other memorable details about the technology level in the story?